# Object has no attribute 'prepare'

Tags: python, django, django-models, prepare

In my django project, I have 4 models that are all tied together in a chain.

Model_D > Model_C > Model_B > Model_A

So Model_C has a foreign key field that points to Model_B, and Model_B has a foreign key field that points to Model_A

When I do a lookup like below, I get the following error

```
Model_D.objects.filter(model_c = object_of_type_c)
```

I get the error "Model_C has no attribute 'prepare'"

But, when I do the lookup like this, I get no error

```
Model_D.objects.filter(model_c__id = object_of_type_c.id)
```

or

```
Model_D.objects.filter(model_c = object_of_type_c.id)
```

I can't even seem to find this error searching here or google. I think it has something to do with how the related objects manager works but I'm stuck.

EDIT: There is a 5th model, Model_E which is also tied to Model_C.  I get the same problem when trying to a lookup on this model as well.  I don't know if this makes any difference.

The weirdest part is that it seems to work fine for doing similar lookups for Model_C, or Model_B.

UPDATE:

http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/13640

Model_C has a method named 'evaluate' which is a reserved name.  Fixes the problem by renaming the method.

I have tried adjusting the related_name values for these models in a number of ways and haven't had any success there either.

Comment: Does it work if you the same query but via the reverse relationship? ie `object_of_type_c.model_d_set.all()`?

Comment: yes. when accessed through the related name I do get the reverse relationship.  Also note that I edited the original post with info about my 5th model which is also tied to model c

Comment: Please post the definition of ModelC.

Comment: popped it in above.  Only changed model name to fit in with my previous naming scheme.  Common info is an abstract base class shared by all of the models that just has created_date and updated_date fields that are auto_now_true and auto_now.

Comment: I found my problem

http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/13640

Model_C has a method called 'evaluate' which evidently is a reserved name.

Comment: Add an answer to your question then mark it as answered just in case someone else has the same problem they can see the solution easier. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/13640

This error arises when you define a method on a model with the name 'evaluate'.  Renaming the method solves the problem.